# Scala 2.10: Array + JSON arrays to hashmap

Tags: json, scala, dictionary, hashmap

After reading a JSON result from a web service response:

```
val jsonResult: JsValue = Json.parse(response.body)
```

Containing content something like:

```
{
    result:  [
    ["Name 1", "Row1 Val1", "Row1 Val2"],
    ["Name 2", "Row2 Val1", "Row2 Val2"]
             ]
 }
```

How can I efficiently map the contents of the result array in the JSON with a list (or something similar) like:

```
val keys = List("Name", "Val1", "Val2")
```

To get an array of hashmaps?

Comment: You should be more explicit about the relationship between the input (the nested `List[List[String]]` and the output (`List[String]`) ... or is the output an "array of [hash]maps"?. And if the sequence of map is in fact the desired final result, it's even less clear how it relates to your input.

Comment: I'm looking for a result that is something like:  List(Map("Name" -> "Name 1", "Val1" -> "Row1 Val1", "Val2" -> "Row1 Val2"), Map("Name" -> "Name 2", "Val1" -> "Row2 Val1", "Val2" -> "Row2 Val2"))

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're really not making your assumptions clear. Please try to specify exactly how the result / output relates to the input. I sense that there is some sort of string manipulation in play, but I can't be sure. I don't mean to be tedious, but this is what programming is about. Being entirely clear and unambiguous about how the output of your program relates to its input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ?
This solution is functional and handles None/Failure cases "properly" (by returning a None)

```
val j = JSON.parseFull( json ).asInstanceOf[ Option[ Map[ String, List[ List[ String ] ] ] ] ]

val res = j.map { m ⇒
    val r = m get "result"
    r.map { ll ⇒
        ll.foldRight( List(): List[ Map[ String, String ] ] ) { ( l, acc ) ⇒
            Map( ( "Name" -> l( 0 ) ), ( "Val1" -> l( 1 ) ), ( "Val2" -> l( 2 ) ) ) :: acc
        }
    }.getOrElse(None) 
}.getOrElse(None)
```

- Note 1: I had to put double quotes around `result` in the JSON String to get the JSON parser to work
- Note 2: the code could look nicer using more "monadic" sugar such as for comprehensions or using applicative functors